# Etiquette of breaking down a large question into a series of smaller ones

Tags: discussion

So I've got something of a monster of a question about the composition and formations of Saladin's army during the siege of Jerusalem. It took a good many hours to research and currently fills four pages of a text document (much of that documenting what I've already learned -- part of it is a 'I'm just a layman, what am I missing here' kind of question). For obvious reasons I'm going to try and edit it, and one option I considered was to break it down into two, three or even four smaller questions. But before I give that a try that wanted to check in about it.

**Is it considered bad form here to post a series of questions on the same topic in succession? And if alright, what would be a good posting rate so I don't end up spamming the board?**

(And as a follow up, so long as I'm here, how long of a question is too long?)

Comment: Unless they become duplicates, the more the merrier, really.

Comment: I would only add: Do your best to keep both the questions and the expected answers disjoint from each other in scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is is preferred, for a variety of reasons.  Tends towards more precise, questions with more clearly authoritative questions.

I prefer longer questions to shorter - so long as the title and question are crystal clear.

tl; dr - bring it on.  A set of questions about a diverse historical character?  sounds good to me.

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit of six questions per site from the same person within a 24 hour period. That was meant to prevent spam.

A good rate might be one or two per day. That way, you keep the (related) questions close together without "flooding" the site at one time.